# VSCode issue after removing GitHub- Cant access old folder directories

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, directory

I tried installing GitHub on Visual Studio Code, but eventually decided to not use it.  After I removed the GitHub extensions, I am no longer able to open or save files in the same manner.  When I go to open a file or save one, I no longer am directed to the old folder directory from before.

A message now appears in the bottom right hand corner that says **"File system provider for vscode-vfs://github/exercise-1-/Untitled-2.ipynb is not available."**

I'm trying to get VSCode to return back to the way it was prior to installing GitHub.  Any ideas what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I just needed to click the icon in the bottom left with a head on it (accounts) and log out of my GitHub account.  Then close Visual Studio entirely and reopen.  Everything seems to be running as it did prior to the GitHub installation.